# Get values from a specific ListView item

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to get some values from the clicked ListView item, so that I can open my new intent with the same Title and Description that the ListView item holds.

I am having a slight bit of trouble doing this, as I have never worked with ListViews until recently. Could somebody help me out with this please?

**SocietySearch.java:**

Specific code is in OnItemClick

```
public class SocietySearch extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //TODO remember notifyDataSetChanged
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_society_search);

        List<Society> societies = new ArrayList<>();
        ServerRequests serverRequest1 = new ServerRequests(SocietySearch.this);
        serverRequest1.GetSocietyDataAsyncTask(societies, new GetSocietyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(final List<Society> societies) {
                final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
                List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
                for (final Society s : societies) {
                    items.add(new ListViewItem() {{
                        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.test;
                        Title = s.socName;
                        Description = s.socDes;
                    }});
                }
                final CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(SocietySearch.this, items);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
                searchView.setQueryHint("Search..");

                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent societyPage = new Intent(SocietySearch.this, SocietyPage.class);
                        startActivity(societyPage);

                        List<ListViewItem> obj = items.getItem(position);
                        //Here I want to get all values from clicked item position and assign them to variables

                        String value = obj.toString();
                        Log.d("MyLog", "Value is: " + value);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public class ListViewItem {
        public int ThumbnailResource;
        public String Title;
        public String Description;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Title;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use a Third party Bus, one of which is `Otto Bus`

Comment: `items.getItem()` returns a single item not a `List` of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I believe the below is not gonna return a list. It's going to return a ListViewItem object.

```
List<ListViewItem> obj = items.getItem(position);
```

If I understand your question correctly. You will want to get the object and pass those values into the intent. Example Below.

```
ListViewItem item = items.getItem(position);
String title = item.Title;
String desc = item. Description;
int thumbnail = item. ThumbnailResource;

Intent societyPage = new Intent(SocietySearch.this, SocietyPage.class);
i.putExtra("title", title);
i.putExtra("desc", desc);
i.putExtra("thumbnail", thumbnail);
startActivity(societyPage);
```

Comment: Well answered! Helped me out a lot, I just changed `ListViewItem item = items.getItem(position);` to `ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)adapter.getAdapter().getItem(position);`